# AS3 - positon advertisment that is dynamically loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, positioning

I'm using the code below to place an ad inside a mobile game that I'm building. My problem is that the ad appears in the top left corner of the stage and I need to be able to move it centered near the bottom. I got this code from a book and I understand about 70% of what it's doing. Thanks for any direction you can offer.

Rich

```
// Smaato Advertising Code for Start Screen

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://soma.smaato.com/oapi/reqAd.jsp");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.adspace = "0";
variables.pub = "0";

variables.devip = "127.0.0.1";
variables.format = "IMG";
variables.adcount = "1";
variables.response = "XML";
request.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(request);


function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
var data:XML = new XML(loader.data as String);
var status:String = data.*::status.toString();
if(status == "success")
{
    var ad:XMLList = data.*::ads.*::ad;
    var link:String = ad.*::link.toString();

    var l:Loader = new Loader();
    l.load(new URLRequest(link));
    addChild(l);
    var clickurl:String = ad.*::action.@target.toString();
    l.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAdClick);

    function onAdClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(clickurl);
        navigateToURL(request);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are never actually positioning the image, so the default is `[0,0]`, the top-left corner of the screen.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://soma.smaato.com/oapi/reqAd.jsp");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.adspace = "0";
variables.pub = "0";

variables.devip = "127.0.0.1";
variables.format = "IMG";
variables.adcount = "1";
variables.response = "XML";
request.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(request);


function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var data:XML = new XML(loader.data as String);
    var status:String = data.*::status.toString();
    if(status == "success")
    {
        var ad:XMLList = data.*::ads.*::ad;
        var link:String = ad.*::link.toString();
        var l:Loader = new Loader();
        l.load(new URLRequest(link));
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onAdLoaded);
        function onAdLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var ad:DisplayObject = e.target.content;
            addChild(ad);
            ad.x = (ad.stage.stageWidth - ad.width)  / 2;
            ad.y = (ad.stage.stageHeight - ad.height) / 2 + 50;
        }
        var clickurl:String = ad.*::action.@target.toString();
        l.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAdClick);
        function onAdClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(clickurl);
            navigateToURL(request);
        }
    }
}
```

That will center the loaded file. The **50** number is because if you don't want it to be in the exact center, you can use the number to adjust the y-value accordingly.

By the way, I recommend you to grab another book, becase the code you are using seems a bit old and have poor performance.

If you have any other issue regarding this, comment it and I can expand my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there a way to get the width of the downloaded ad so that I can center it. From what I understand ads can be a few different widths.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the code. The changes are that now you have an EVENT_COMPLETE when loading the ad, because before you know the width and height of an asset, you first need to load it. Try the code and tell me if it works.

Comment: I get an error on the line with the new function. "The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions." If I remove the word private it chokes even more.

Comment: Ok, I updated it again. Sorry, I didn't know you were using the Flash IDE, it was my mistake.

Comment: I'm getting a "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." on the onAdLoaded. I think it's this line:

Comment: l.x = (l.stage.stageWidth - ad.width)  / 2;

Comment: I think we are close. Getting the following error now "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed." I know the ads are available because under the first code you gave me they pop right up.

Comment: It is pulling in the add some of the time afterall but the link no longer works if you click on the ad. And How would I remove this ad on the next frame? Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: Hi, to remove the ad you would call [removeChild](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild%28%29) function. I'm not sure about your problem with the link. It isn't opening the browser window?